# SignalR response not recognised on client side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a notes feature that allows users to submit notes. When the submit button is clicked, everything works perfectly and all parameters are sent to the server. The server inserts the values into a sql database and that also works fine.

The problem is that when it's time for the server to send data to any active clients on the page, the method is not invoked on the client side.

Client Side

```
"use strict";

var connectionNotes = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/NotesHub", { skipNegotiation: true, transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets }).build();

//Disable the send button until connection is established.
document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = true;

connectionNotes.on("ReceiveNotes", function (user, message) {
    alert("test")
    // this is a test whether it's something to do with the code inside the function, and it's not
});

connectionNotes.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("sendButton").disabled = false;
    connectionNotes.invoke("AddToGroup", window.location.href).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var data1 = document.getElementById("data").getAttribute("[id retracted]");
    var data2 = document.getElementById("data").getAttribute("[id retracted]");
    var data3 = document.getElementById("messageInput").value.replaceAll(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '#newline#');
    document.getElementById("messageInput").value = "";
    if (messageNotes.replaceAll("#newline#", "").length > 0) {
        connectionNotes.invoke("SendMessage", data1, data2, data3, window.location.href).catch(function (err) {
            return console.error(err.toString());
        });
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Server Side

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace [retracted].Hubs
{
    public class NotesHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string id, string user, string message, string groupName)
        {
            // some sql
            
            await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("ReceiveNotes", username, message);

            //more sql here
        }

        public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Two directions I can think of: 1. use debugger to see if `SendMessage` and `AddToGroup` are called in correct order. 2. use Clients.All first to test if it's group problem.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang I've tried both already. Sendmessage and AddToGroup are called in correct order and it still doesn't workwith .All

Comment: Inside the F12 network's websoket, did the client receive the server response?

Comment: @BrandoZhang how would I check that?

Comment: Use browser F12 and click network and inside the request click the websocket connection.

Comment: @BrandoZhang the browser is receiving a response with correct params

Comment: I have tired your codes and it works well on my side, I don't modify your coeds. It shows the alert. I suggest you could try to use a new browser and test agian.